# Getting 404 error when trying to include angular.min.js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new to angular JS and trying to add angular.min.js file in my html file. the path is correct as it is working for other included js file but i am getting 404 error for angular.min.js file . Do I need to make any other configurations? 
below it is working for friends.js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= "/WebServices/js/friends.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "/WebServices/js/angular.min.js"></script>
```

[response in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXfdX.jpg)
 my web.xml file

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

folder structure :WebServices is the project name.: [folder structure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tOUw.jpg)

Comment: Is the `angular.min.js` file in the same folder as `friends.js`?

Comment: yes they both are in the same folder . added folder structure also.

Comment: Then a simple `angular.min.js` should suffice. You don't need the full URI; in fact, try to avoid the full (absolute) URI wherever possible. Also, the change that it's working for `friends.js` may be the fact that there is a nested directory within `WebServices` with the file under the folder `js`.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: after OP posted more information**

You have an absolute path to the `WebServices` folder. You might want to check that out? Does the `WebServices` folder have a nested `js` folder with the `friends.js` file? It's highly possible. The path to your `angular.min.js` should be (wrt WebServices): `/WebServices/WebContent/js/angular.min.js`. Try to point the browser to this URL and check if it works. If it does, it means that you have place `friends.js` in the `WebServices` directory; I am assuming that you might want to change that. If it doesn't, there is a problem with your webserver. Before I make the latter assumption, can you (if possible) tell us the root path of the server? Is it `WebContent` or `WebServices`?

---

One of the suspected problems here can be the fact that you're specifying the absolute URI: i.e., `/path/to/file`. Web servers, commonly, interpret this as the full URl to the file. So, if the above `index.html` file is in the `public` directory, it won't go to `path` in the folder where `index.html` is location; instead, it'll go to the root folder of the current domain.

Say the web server root is a directory called `server` and your directory structure is:

```
├── public
│   ├── index.html
│   └── js
│       └── index.js
└── root
```

And in `index.html` you have the following bit of code:

```
<script src="/js/index.js"></script>
```

The web server will try to fetch the data from the container folder, i.e. `server`. It's a simple mistake, but a common one.

Tell us a little bit more, and we might help you resolve it. Be sure to mention the root configuration and the directory structure.

Comment: I have added the folder structure in the questions .i am using rest services and trying to integrate it with angularJS. i am suspecting some issue in my web.xml.

Comment: Try pointing your browser to `/WebServices/WebContent/js/angular.min.js`. Works?

Comment: the root path is WebServices . i have tried with both <script type="text/javascript" src= "angular.min.js"></script>and <script type="text/javascript" src= "/WebServices/WebContent/js/angular.min.js"></script>. But getting 404 in both cases . Also  "http://localhost:8081/WebServices/friends.html" is my page url .

Comment: Yeah, if that's the case `/WebServices` can't work since there is not sub-directory within `WebServices`. Try `/WebContent/js/angular.min.js`. I presume this should work.

Comment: hi i have tried this also <script type="text/javascript" src= "/WebContent/js/angular.min.js"></script> but no luck . :(

Comment: Alright, it appears that the server is misconfigured. Can you get a directory listing in the `/` path. To do that, just rename `index.html` to `_index.html`. The server should show you a listing of that directory. Thereon, you can see where you are and find the file you need to reference.

Comment: hi, the problem is solved with <script type="text/javascript" src= "/WebServices/js/angular.min.js"></script>. @weirdpanda thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh, cool! Did you solve it using the method I told? Or was there some server problem?

Comment: i was not restarting the server . it got resolved after server restart. thanks again..